# Как создать файл со случайным названием?

Tags: javascript, php, html, php5

Мне нужно создать файл с рандомным названием

Comment: `file_put_contents(uniqid() . '.txt', "Content");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$file = substr(md5(time()), 0, 8) .'.txt'; // 8 - количество символов
$text = "це текст-'риба', що використовується в друкарстві та дизайні";
file_put_contents($file, $text);
```